# How to change a DIV's actions in media CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following section in html but I require to change the font size of the H2 tag and position through media query as it is only suitable for laptop.  I am not sure how to translate it into CSS and work as it is not just an image or piece of text.

```html
<section id="slide-2" class="homeSlide">
  <div class="bcg" data-center="background-position: 50% 10px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 100px;" data-anchor-target="#slide-2">
    <div class="hsContainer">
      <div class="hsContent" data-center="opacity: 1" data-center-top="opacity: 0" data--100-bottom="opacity: 0;" data-anchor-target="#slide-2">
        <h2>Luxurious Jaguar XF 6 Turbo Twin</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: for example, use: `@media (max-width: 1200px) {...}` and add styles in it whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can either write your CSS in a separate file and link to it in your html, or you could use put your CSS between style tags in your html. [Here's an example of how to do either.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

In your CSS here's how you would write custom rules for you H2 tag:

```
h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
}
```

As for media queries, those can also be made in your CSS. Here's a simple example of how to create a rule that would only be applied when the screen is less than 800px wide:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    h2 {
      font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

[Here's some more examples and explanations on how to make media queries.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) Good luck!

Comment: Hi yes I understand media queries but I do not understand them when I need to change an actual div as in the question other than  {display:none}

Comment: You would do it exactly the same way, except change the property of the div instead of an h2 as I have show.